# Chrome WebSpeech API returning not-allowed error?

Tags: reactjs, webspeech-api

I was using Web Speech API for speech to text. But when calling recognition.start() it is showing me SpeechRecognitionErrorEvent

```
recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition()
recognition.continuous = false
recognition.interimResults = false

recognition.onend = () => console.log("ended")

recognition.onerror = () => console.log("errored")

recognition.start()
```

Its logging,

```
errored
ended
SpeechRecognitionErrorEvent {isTrusted: true, error: "not-allowed", message: "", type: "error", target: SpeechRecognition, …}
```

I tried it in my react project. Trying to trigger the recognizer from chrome console also results in the same error.
Someone else, as I am using it for the first time I cannot quite grasp the reason for this error. Another question with the same issue was raised in stackoverflow from where I couldn't got an clear answer. Is it that I must request the speech api start method with a ssl certificate. Otherwise, I cannot use the feature.

UPDATE:
I had to enable microphone permission manually in the browser to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
  const SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
  const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();

  recognition.start()
```

Comment: Tried that already.. faced the same issue

Comment: Can you drop a codesandbox link with reproduced issue

Comment: Everything is working on my system, maybe there is some problem with your system settings. Try on some other device

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, another reason this error can occur is if you are sending a `Permissions-Policy` header ([W3C Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/permissions-policy-1/)) in your HTTP responses and include the string `microphone=()` to disable access to the microphone. This header is typically used to prevent malicious third-party scripts from asking for the microphone.